# How to redirect all urls with matching keyword to one single url?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, match, keyword

I need to redirect all urls with matching keyword, regardless of position in link, to one single url on same site.

Example:

Links with word "book"

www.domain.com/booklovers.php

www.domain.com/booksforall.php

www.domain.com/bestbooksonamazon.php

www.domain.com/somethingaboutbooks.php

to be redirected to one single url on same domain,

www.domain.com/books.php

For now, I am focusing on

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*book.*$ /books.php [L,QSA]
```

but it is not working.
I tested same expression

```
^.*book.*$
```

in tester on http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/ and it works, but in .htaccess it does not work. I am reading various answers here and learned a lot on other examples, but I can not find nothing for my case.

Comment: Sorry, minutes after the posting questions here I figured - .php missing. Expression is like this    ^.*book.*\.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this after making sure AllowOverride is set to All in your virtualhost config and that mod_rewrite is enabled:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule book books.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, will try that solution, too. I managed to fix it few minutes after posting, I forgot on \.php part.